# Face detection and replacement in photos

Tags: computer-vision, image-recognition, object-detection, image-processing, face-recognition

I have 2 photos, and my goal is to detect the face in one and place it on the face of the person in the other photo- basically face detection and replacement. It's not deep fakes. It's more of a computer vision-based approach for smoothing the edges and stitching.

How can we achieve that? What are the approaches and techniques to do that? Some tutorials or code or github repos would be very helpful.

[image]